# Execution of Int, Decimal or Datetime Types in Bottle and MySQLdb Not Working

Tags: python, mysql, bottle, pythonanywhere

I'm getting a very strange error while using MySQLdb in Bottle on PythonAnywhere.com

Whenever the execute contains columns of type int, decimal or datetime, the execute throws a 500 error. For example, from a table Tools, manufacturer and sub_type are both varchars, so this block of code works perfectly:

```
reservation_id = request.forms.get("reservation_id")
db = MySQLdb.connect("...")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("""SELECT manufacturer, sub_type FROM Tool""")
row = c.fetchone()
return row
```

But ask for the tool_id from that same table, which is of int type, or any other column of int, decimal or datetime type from that table:

```
reservation_id = request.forms.get("reservation_id")
db = MySQLdb.connect("...")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("""SELECT tool_id FROM Tool""")
row = c.fetchone()
return row
```

And Bottle throws a critical error:

Error running WSGI application
SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

In MySQL bash, every query works perfectly. Put that same query (only int, decimal or datetime) in execute(), and it fails.

Has anyone had any similar experience?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you included the stack trace and Bottle framework code in your question, but I'll take a stab at it since I have a hunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you returning `row` as your WSGI response? If so, that's the problem. According to [the WSGI standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#id18):

> When called by the server, the application object must return an iterable yielding zero or more strings.

To illustrate this, try converting your row to a string first and confirm that that helps. E.g.,

```
...  # your existing code
return [str(col) for col in row]
```

Comment: You're awesome! That did it, thank you! I owe you a coffee if we ever cross paths!